# Can you close all connections to MongoDB from the Mongo Shell?

Tags: mongodb

Can you close all connections to MongoDB from the Mongo Shell? If so, what is the proper command?

Thank you.

Comment: did you find any answer about quieting mongodb from shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to block connections from the shell.

However, if you were trying to block writes for a backup, then you can do that.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was curious if I could shut connections via the shell if I found a Web application had leaked connections.